# How to Catch Exception in youtube-dl in python?

Tags: python, exception, youtube-dl

I use youtube-dl in python, sometime I got ContentTooShortError, how can I use "try...catch..." in python to deal with these exceptions?

I use this code but it doesn't work

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    # youtube_url = video.youtube_url
    n = 0
    try:
        # 用设置成list的形式
        ydl.download([video.youtube_url])
    except 'ContentTooShortError':
        if n + 1 < max_retey:
            ydl.download([video.youtube_url])
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes. The exception class need not be added as a string.

```
except ContentTooShortError:
```

And as mentioned by @MichalPawlowski in the comments, make sure you import it.

```
# For Python 3
from urllib.error import ContentTooShortError

# For Python 2
from urllib import ContentTooShortError
```

Comment: And remember to import `ContentTooShortError` first.